# Call a string from GUI class - VariableDeclarators error

Tags: java, string

I've created a program to browse an excel file and modify it using ***windowbuilder*** and ***Apache POI***.

I've created a public string for the file path, as follows.

```
public class UI {

    public static String filename;

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Excel Files", "xlsx");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                File file= chooser.getSelectedFile();
                filename=file.getAbsolutePath();
```

And Called the String to the main code to get the file path to continue the process.

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {

    UI.filename;

    File file= new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

When I run the GUI, I get the following error message,

> Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete LocalVariableDeclaration
>           filename cannot be resolved to a variable

```
new File(filename);
```

This part shoud be something like this

```
File file= new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Project\\Data.xlsx");
```

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Code needs to be run from within a valid "execution" context - ie like a method

Comment: This is unclear.  First, Java is not Javascript, and there is no Javascript in your question. I've removed the extraneous tag.  Second, The statement _"Call a string from [a] class"_ does not mean anything in Java.  I presume you think the statement `UI.filename;` somehow causes the member variable to appear in the main method... it does not, and this is a fundamental misconception about how Java works.  I suggest you start with the basic [Java tutorials at Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Can you please explain that ?
I am a beginner to java.
When I run the main with a fixed file path, it is working correctly and the GUI itself runs properly. The problem is when I try to call the string from UI to Main class.

Comment: I really strongly suggest you go through the tutorials.  Take the time now and save lots of time later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code in Java needs to executed from within a "executable" context.  In your case, that means a method within a class.

You need to start by changing your `UI` class to supply a `static` method which performs the operations you want...

```
public class UI {

    public static File selectFile() {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Excel Files", "xlsx");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        return chooser.getSelectedFile();
    }
```

Then you need to update your `main` method to take advantage of this change...

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File file = UI.selectFile();
            if (file == null) {
                System.out.println("No file selected");
            }

            FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
        }
    });
```